# Join tables on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three tables:
Product, Object, Info - Product has_many Objects through Product_Objects ...
Object has_many Info, Product has_many Info.

What do I need:
I want to access the values from a column in Info table.

How I do it now:

```
 data = @product.objects
 data.infos.where('date(created_at) IN (?)', dates).where(product_id: @product.id).each do |d|
    d.value
 end
```

(dates: Date.today, Date.today - 1.day, Date.today - 1.week, Date.today - 1.month)

Is there a way to this differently, because I have a lot of records, and is very slow.

Expected result: [name, value]
Name is a column in the Object table and value is a integer from the Info table, column value.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed it up by getting rid of `date` function and by using `pluck` instead of iterating over all records (assuming `value` is a column on `Info` model). To do this, create a scope on `Info` model:

```
scope :created_at, ->(dates) { where(created_at: Array.wrap(dates).map {|date| date..(date + 1.day)}) }
```

Then you can call:

```
data = @product.objects
data.infos.created_at(dates).where(product_id: @product.id).pluck(:value)
```

UPDATE:

Since those two columns are on separate tables, you will need to use `joins` method. This makes it slightly trickier to use the scope defined above - we need to use merge. ALso pluck do not allows to get more than one column at the time, so we need to use nice `select_all` trick:

```
data = @product.objects
query = data.joins(:infos).merge(Info.created_at(dates)).where(product_id: @product.id).select([:name, :value])
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query)
```

Comment: Could you describe what `value` is - it looks like it is not a column?

Comment: the value is a integer, and is a column in the info table

Comment: Than pluck should do the trick. I have updated answer to get :name as well - are you getting any errors running the above?

Comment: Yes I do, because `name` is a column in the `Object` table, and `value` is a column in the `Info` table.

Comment: doesn't work because it can't find the product_id column

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45124/discussion-between-broisatse-and-alex)